# TableViewCell not displaying custom cell info

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a tableview that gets its information from devices in persistent data store which is updated when something happens.  This update works fine.

Anyway I get the data and load it into my TableDataVainView.plist and have the tableView reload the data.  Trouble is the cell lines are there but no data.

I have checked that the data exists and it is being populated in the cell.textLabel and cell.detailTextLabel but again it doesn't appear.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Cell"];
    self.tableDataMainView = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cell"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext
                      executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    for (context in items) {
        NSLog(@"Title: %@,", [context name]);
    }
    cellNamesArray = [items valueForKey:@"image"];
    NSLog(@"cellNameArray;%@",cellNamesArray);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];

self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 0);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *slasha = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Names"];
    NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:slasha error:nil];

    NSString *slashb = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];
    NSArray * directoryContentsImages = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:slashb error:nil];

    int pictureCount;

    for (pictureCount = 0; pictureCount < (int)[directoryContentsImages count]; pictureCount++)
    {

        NSLog(@"File %d: %@", (pictureCount + 1), [directoryContentsImages objectAtIndex:pictureCount]);
    }

    NSLog(@"count:%d,",count);
    NSLog(@"picturecount:%d,",pictureCount);
for (count = 0; count < (int)[directoryContents count]; count++)
    {

        NSLog(@"File %d: %@", (count + 1), [directoryContents objectAtIndex:count]);
    }

    NSLog(@"count:%d,",count);
    Names = [NSArray arrayWithArray:directoryContents];

    NSLog(@"namesArray;%@",Names);
    if (count == 0) {

    }
    else if (count == 1) {
        nameOne = [Names objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"nameOne;%@",nameOne);
        NSArray *coorArray = [nameOne componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *firstString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *secondString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"firstString;%@",firstString);
        NSLog(@"secondString;%@",secondString);
    }
    else if (count == 2) {
        nameOne = [Names objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwo =[Names objectAtIndex:1];
        NSArray *coorArray = [nameOne componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *firstString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *secondString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"firstString;%@",firstString);
        NSLog(@"secondString;%@",secondString);
        NSArray *coorArray2 = [nameTwo componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *firstString2 = [coorArray2 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *secondString2 = [coorArray2 objectAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"firstString2;%@",firstString2);
        NSLog(@"secondString2;%@",secondString2);
    }

    else if (count == 3) {
        nameOne = [Names objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *nameTwo =[Names objectAtIndex:1];
         NSString *nameThree =[Names objectAtIndex:1];
        NSArray *coorArray = [nameOne componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *firstString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *secondString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"firstString;%@",firstString);
        NSLog(@"secondString;%@",secondString);
        NSArray *coorArray2 = [nameTwo componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *firstString2 = [coorArray2 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *secondString2 = [coorArray2 objectAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"firstString2;%@",firstString2);
        NSLog(@"secondString2;%@",secondString2);
        NSArray *coorArray3 = [nameThree componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *firstString3 = [coorArray3 objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *secondString3 = [coorArray3 objectAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"firstString3;%@",firstString3);
        NSLog(@"secondString3;%@",secondString3);
    }}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"number of sections called");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   NSLog(@"got row count");

    return self.tableDataMainView.count;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"index path");
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSLog(@"Cell");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    device = [self.tableDataMainView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"name"]];
    NSLog(@"celltextlabel%@",cell.textLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"deviceName???%@",device);
    cell.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(16, 35, 200, 65);
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"winloss"]];
    NSLog(@"celldetailtextlabel%@",cell.detailTextLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"devicewinloss???%@",device);

   [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
    NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                          NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *slash3 = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];


    NSString *fullPath1 = [slash3 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[device valueForKey:@"image"]];

    //Now load the image at fullPath and install it into our image view's image property.
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath1]){

    }
    else {

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: fullPath1];
        NSLog(@"fullPath1:%@",fullPath1);
    }

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    return cell;
 }
```

Like I said this used to work fine but then it stopped working.
I do hard code some background views but not the tableView which is set in the IB.  But since I can see the cell division lines I'm thinking that the table view is on top.  I have tied the datasource and delegate to the tableView.  Just not sure why it isn't displaying the cell info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
So as I came to suspect I have two backgrounds that are put in place by code ie.
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundImage atIndex:0];

    backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tilebackground long.png"];

self.backgroundImage2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"just stars long.png"];
    backgroundImage2.hidden = NO;
    [self.view insertSubview:backgroundImage2 atIndex:1];
```

since my tableView is created in the IB it resides atIndex:0

By changing my code to put backgroundImage atIndex:-2 and 
backgroundImage2 atIndes:-1
My tableView now is displayed, but it has a black background so I can't see my two backgroundImages.

In the IB I have made the tableview background clear and in code as well as the cell's background but still there is a black background.

Since this is still the problem of the tableView I thought I would amend this to see how to make the tableView background clear.  If I need to I can ask another question and mark this one done.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, 
`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

This shows there is a lot of hassles as it is not prepared by yourself. The returned cell may be not as same as the designed one.

An easy quick fix to this is to use a customized UITableViewCell. Then register as the CellIdentifier in tableViewController.  So you can customize in your nib/xib file especially if time is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your `viewDidAppear` method does not call:

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
```

This may or may not be the underlying problem, but it will lead to undefined behaviour. Make that the first line in `viewDidAppear`.

Another tip would be to get the misbehaving table view on the screen, and then use the 'debug view hierarchy' feature in Xcode. It's like a breakpoint, but for views. You'll be able to see exactly what is on the screen and in what ordering.